# Time-frame of cap exemption & validity of a new H-1B visa for former H-1B holder

Tags: working-visas, immigration, h1-visa

I have a specific question regarding the time-frame of cap exemption granted for former H1-B visa holders. I have read various conflicting/confusing articles on this online that the time-frames become muddled due to verbiage.

I have held a H1-B visa from **October 1, 2012** through **June 6, 2014**  (20 months & 6 days) when I resigned my job and left the USA for PhD studies elsewhere. Having completed the PhD, I am now interested in returning to the USA for work. I am currently looking for employment in for-profit private companies different to original one that sponsored my original H1-B visa.

The questions are:

- Until what calendar date am I exempt from capping for my next H1-B visa?
- If a company does indeed sponsor a H1-B, **how long** will the newly issued visa be valid for?